# code to emulate what the .split() function does in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make a program for a school project. It has to do what the `.split()` function does in Python. But I have to write it from scratch.

So far I can't get it to add anything more than ONE space to the list and I need it to add an infinite number of strings. If I give it more than one character, it won't leave the loop. I'm also not allowed to use `break`.

```
sent = input("Give a sentence here:")

List=[]
Bpoint=0
Epoint=0
inString=[Bpoint,Epoint]

Epoint=+1
x=True
while x==True:
    if Epoint >= len(sent):
            x=False
    elif Epoint < len(sent):
        if sent[Epoint] == chr(32):
            List.append(inString[Bpoint:Epoint])
            Bpoint=Epoint + 1
            x=False
            if Epoint >= len(sent):
                x=False
            elif Epoint < len(sent):
                x=True
        elif sent[Epoint] != chr(32):
            if Epoint >= len(sent):
                x=False
            elif Epoint < len(sent):
                x=True
            Epoint=+1
        else:
            print ("Somethings wrong. Close and start over.")
print (List)
```

Comment: Is it meant to do *exactly* what `split` does? E.g. should it take sep and maxsplit params as well as the string? Do you need to make this a function?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would go about fixing this up.

Firstly, rename variables, tidy up style:

```
sentence = input("Give a sentence here:")

results = []
word_start = 0
word_end = 0
in_string = [word_start, word_end]

word_end = 1
running = True

while running:
    if word_end >= len(sentence):
        running = False
        continue

    # If we get here, we know that `word_end < len(sentence)`
    if sentence[word_end] == " ":  # chr(32) was just confusing
        results.append(sentence[word_start:word_end])  # Note that using inString was wrong here
        word_start = word_end + 1
        running = False
        if word_end >= len(sentence):
            running = False
        else:  # We know `word_end < len(sent)` must be True
            running = True

    else:  # We know `sentence[word_end] != " "` must be True, no need to check
        if word_end >= len(sent):
            running = False
        else:  # No need for the elif check, because logic
            running = True
        word_end += 1  # Fixed typo error =+ vs +=
    # else: The 'something wrong' could never be reached. Either a character is a space, or not a space - there is no 3rd option!

print(results)
```

The code is broadly unchanged from a structure point of view, but at least now it's easier to see what's going on. The next stage is to start fixing the structure. The first thing I notice is that we have the start-of-word and end-of-word counters and we need to maintain them manually. That's a bit ugly, so we can replace the while loop with a for loop that `enumerate`s over the sentence. I also notice that in_string isn't used properly, so we will get rid of it:

```
sentence = input("Give a sentence here:")

results = []
word_start = 0

for current_index, letter in enumerate(sentence):

    if sentence[current_index] == " ":
        # We've found a split between two words. See if we can add the previous word
        word = sentence[word_start:current_index]
        results.append(word)
        word_start = current_index + 1

        # Look at all the counter logic we've removed!

print(results)
```

So now I run it, and I discover that it's not finding the last word:

```
Give a sentence here:Hi Tom this is a test
['Hi', 'Tom', 'this', 'is', 'a']
```

So after we get to the end of the sentence, we're dropping out of the loop because we haven't got a space to trigger the add-word code. We can prove this theory by entering "Hi Tom this is a test " (note the last space):

```
Give a sentence here:Hi tom this is a test 
['Hi', 'tom', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

OK, so that was the problem, now we need to fix it. I'll leave that to you :-) There are still a few things after that that will need to be improved/fixed (What happens if you enter `"Hello      world"`?), but you'll need to discover those yourself! Good luck!